# Scan a database table periodically for new rows

Tags: java, mysql

I have a Java application that reads rows from table A and writes those rows to table B.

Now, my other requirement is to check table A periodically (every x minutes) for newly inserted rows and move them to table B. If it helps, table A has `created_at` and `updated_at` TIMESTAMP fields.

Is there any way I can check for newly inserted rows in a certain interval, based on the TIMESTAMP value, add those new rows to a List and re-use the Java method that I already have, to write to table B?

I'm a Java/MySQL noob and would highly appreciate any advice/suggestion that'd help me get started. I'm using MariaDB database.

Comment: If the timestamps are strictly chronological you can take the timestampe of the most recent record in B, and copy from A to B, everything that is most recent.

Comment: You could also use a trigger for that. You can create a trigger such as every time a row is interted to A, an action is performed so that it adds to B. [Docs for mariaDB triggers](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-trigger/)

Comment: This doesn't sound like such a great idea. What's the reason behind it?

Comment: What doesn't sound like a great idea?

Comment: Don't, use a trigger to automaticaly insert into table  `B` on every `INSERT` done in `A`. This doesn't required you to keep a `Connection` opened to read the table. This will be done by the DBMS directly.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:** One way you can do this by adding an additional column indicating status as either active or processed. Once the row is picked from Table A and sent to Table B you can update the status of the column as Processed. This can be done using simple update SQL query. You can keep checking the table A after every X min for any record with status as open with a simple select query like `select * from order_book where status = ' OPEN'`.

**Method 2:** You can use a trigger that as soon as the record is inserted in Table A send the record to Table B. Benefit of this method is that it doesn't required you to keep a Connection opened to read the table. This will be done by the DBMS directly

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_UpdateTableB ON TableA
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO 
    TableB
    (
        primary_column,
        column_tableA

    )
    SELECT 
        primary_column, 
        column_tableB, 
       
    FROM 
        INSERTED
END
```

**Method 3:** You can also achieve a similar thing easily using Apache Camel.

```
<route>
<!--To set up a route that generates an event every 60 seconds -->
<from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=60000" />  
      <to uri="sqlComponent:{{sql.selectTableA}}" />
            <to uri="sqlComponent:{{sql.updateStatus}}" />
               <to uri="sqlComponent:{{sql.InsertTableB}}" />
</route>
```

**Method 4:** You can also create a Scheduled Job in java using ScheduledExecutorService. You can configure the scheduled job to run maybe once in an hour (according to the use case) and pick up new records from table A and insert them into table B.

**Appendix** -
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/trigger-overview/ To read more about triggers in MariaDB

http://camel.apache.org/getting-started.html To know more about Apache Camel

https://mkyong.com/java/java-scheduledexecutorservice-examples/

Comment: Thanks for the head start. I will look into it and see how it goes.

Comment: Solution 2 is better, solution 3 is nice if the selected data are needed outside the DB (like exporting every new data, sending a mail, ...) but it requires a connection...

Comment: How is Solution 2 triggered? Via a script that is ran every night?

Comment: @EamonMac No, its a database trigger. A database trigger is special stored procedure that is run when specific actions occur within a database.  Most triggers are defined to run when changes are made to a table’s data.  Triggers can be defined to run instead of or after DML actions such as INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE.